# Akonadi mysqld using 2GB memory even after reboot (Arch Linux, Plasma 5)

Tags: plasma5

I have Arch Linux with Plasma 5. Today I disabled tmpfs as described in archlinux wiki (that is `systemctl mask tmp.mount` and creating custom file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf`).

Then I played with creating big files in folder /tmp (for example `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/large.dat count=2097152` gives me a 1GB file). When I created them I noticed, that mysqld started using more ram. Now I deleted all big files that I created. I rebooted several times and after each one I see that mysqld used about 2GB of RAM. I haven't any unusual programs/scripts in autostart. I have ordinary Arch Linux installation. I know that I can disable akonadi, but is there any other solution?

[image: memory usage with <code>ps aux</code>]
[image: memory usage with system monitor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is jemalloc to be blamed. Either downgrade jemalloc:

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/jemalloc-4.2.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

or upgrade the system with already in the repo jemalloc 4.3.1-1

https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/j/jemalloc/